# Bitmap vs. Vector Graphics: Building Sprites

Tags: sprites, art

I'm currently doing game development of my own I heard that bitmap is much cleaner than Vector graphics since it appear to show up ugly in pixel form?  What's better shown in a 2D art form?

Comment: You question is very unclear.  You should edit it to include what problems you've experienced with one format or another.  If you haven't tried to compare them yourself, you probably should do that first.  What format makes a "better shown 2D art form" is not an answerable question.

Comment: yea, well I guess I wasn't so clear the only program I have tryed is GIMP for art, that's just it really.

Comment: You should draw a sprite in a game.  **IF** it looks bad, then go about determining why.  Don't ponder about formats when you ought to be making a game.

Comment: Your exactly the read to see what comes me, I'll have to look into it deeper, I'll look up and try inkscape. When I can take the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should stay at bitmaps, since they are much easier to handle, especially for a beginner. For example, storing pixels are easier: it takes only 24 bits, or **maybe** 32 bits sometimes - but it means that it can display millions of colours.